# Data truncated for column

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hello im try to insert data from phpmyadmin on my table but i got error like this

```
1 row affected. Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'value' at row 1
```

for my talble is like this

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `setting` (
  `setting_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `group` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `value` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `serialized` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=28279 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

i try put around 5000 data and i can input around 2000 after it when i try insert its say error data truncate thanks.

Comment: Show us your INSERT query..

Comment: I believe your data for `value` column is larger than its limits (64 kB)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data truncated for column obviously means that your data is too wide to fit into the column specified. It's for the `value` field, which is of type [text](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html) the text field can accomodate only 65K of data. You need a bigger type. Maybe MEDIUMTEXT which can accomodate 16MB of data.

BTW, since you are actually storing binary data in your column. MEDIUMBLOB might actually be a better option.

Last but not least :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-optimization-tips.html

> With Web servers, store images and other binary assets as files, with
>   the path name stored in the database rather than the file itself. Most
>   Web servers are better at caching files than database contents, so
>   using files is generally faster. (Although you must handle backups and
>   storage issues yourself in this case.)